# Google reCaptcha doesn't work in AWS

Tags: jsp, amazon-web-services, recaptcha

I entered google reCaptcha version 2 for the site. when it is in the local machine it is work and after put in to the aws it does not work and tell that 'Invlid domain for site key'. For the same domain it is working on local machine.

Comment: What is your website domain? Did you insert your domains to key setting in https://www.google.com/recaptcha/

Comment: www.unisets.com. But temerolty um using the aws http://54.169.5.239:8080/unisets like this

Comment: Add these domains to key settings domains.

Comment: I have already entered the the site keys. it is working in the local. but not working in the AWS